# Why cannot I declare my class name as Map?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map map = new HashMap();

        map.put("father", "Rob");
        System.out.println(map.get("father"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "But not running" doesn't describe your problem clearly at all. Please read [mcve] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call your main class "Map" - it's clashing with java.util.Map

Comment: Can you explain why can't we use Map as a class name?

Comment: @SamyakJain He already did: *it's clashing with `java.util.Map`.* When you write `Map map = ...`, which `Map` are you referring to? Your own class or the one from `import java.util.*`? Answer: Your own.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right java map, it will logically take the one you defined instead. If you really need to use Map for your class you have to use fully qualified name:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Map map = new java.util.HashMap();

    map.put("father", "Rob");
    System.out.println(map.get("father"));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Fontenele